# iOS App can't be validated because of + sign in executable file - but I can't change executable file

Tags: ios, file, build, executable

The thing is that I choose to name my iOS project "Vika+", but the + sign in the name is also included in every other title, including my executable file name. So iTunes Connect is complaining over the + sign telling me to change the executable file name.

My problem is that every time I change the executable file name, the build fails, and then I'm out of options. I don't know what to do next... Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html

> The UTI Character Set A uniform type identifier is a Unicode string
>   that usually contains characters in the ASCII character set. However,
>   only a subset of the ASCII characters are permitted. You may use the
>   Roman alphabet in upper and lower case (A–Z, a–z), the digits 0
>   through 9, the dot (“.”), and the hyphen (“-”). This restriction is
>   based on DNS name restrictions, set forth in RFC 1035.
>
> Uniform type identifiers may also contain any of the Unicode
>   characters greater than U+007F.
>
> Important: Any illegal character appearing in a UTI string—for
>   example, underscore ("_"), colon (":"), or space (" ")—will cause the
>   string to be rejected as an invalid UTI. At the API layer, no error is
>   generated for invalid UTIs.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you should just be able to change the executable name, so just quickly tried changing the name in one of my projects, and I too got a build failure - and worst of all it was a signing related failure.

Best bet is probably to just rename the project to something like VikaPlus and then (If you absolutely have to) change the bundle/product name etc back to Vika+.  Though generally best to avoid characters like + & ^ etc, especially when related to filenames as they cause lots of issues depending on the OS involved as quite often the + is used to represent appending files etc

Comment: I really wanted to use Vika+ as the title for my app but it really doesn't matter because you choose the title in iTunes Connect.